# XSL: Exclude element with starts-with condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML File :

```
<ID>
    <T1>
        <T2>XXXXX</T2>
        <T2>XXXXX</T2>
    </T1>
    <T3>
        <T4>
        <TxId>AAAXXXXXXXXXXX</TxId>
        </T4>       
        <T4>
        <TxId>BBBXXXXXXXXXXX</TxId>
        </T4>    
        <T4>
        <TxId>BBXXXXXXXXXXX</TxId>
        </T4>  ....
```

I need to exclude T4 element when 3 first char of TxId = AAA

I have tried that :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!--Identity template, 
        provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--More specific template for Node766 that provides custom behavior -->
    <xsl:template match="T4">  
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="TxId[not(starts-with(.,'AAA'))]"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to exclude T4 element when 3 first char of TxId = AAA

If you want to exclude certain `<T4>` elements, then you should apply the predicate when matching "T4" - not when selecting their children.

---

For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="T4[not(starts-with(TxId,'AAA'))]">  
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="T4"/> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
<xsl:template match="T4">  
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="TxId[not(starts-with(.,'AAA'))]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You need something like

```
<xsl:template match="T4[TxId[starts-with(.,'AAA')]]" priority="2">  
</xsl:template>
```

In other words, for any T4 element, you want the stylesheet to use the identity template and copy the T4 recursively, *unless* it matches this second template. In the latter case, output nothing (the template is empty).

This second template has a higher default priority than the identity template, because of its match pattern; but I like to make the priority explicit so we can easily see that the second template is intended to override, when it matches.

Comment: Doh! I really shouldn't be posting when the neighbors are noisy. Thanks for making this simple.